# Select rows from a data frame according to another vector, including repetitions

Tags: r, vector, dataframe, subset, repeat

Example data:

```
dates=seq(as.POSIXct("2015-01-01 00:00:00"), as.POSIXct("2015-01-07 00:00:00"), by="day")
data=rnorm(7,1,2)
groupID=c(12,14,16,24,35,46,54)

DF=data.frame(Date=dates,Data=data,groupID=groupID)

BB=c(12,12,16,24,35,35)
DF[DF$groupID %in% BB,]

        Date       Data groupID
1 2015-01-01  4.4104202       12
3 2015-01-03  2.1557735       16
4 2015-01-04 -0.9880946       24
5 2015-01-05 -0.3396025       35
```

I need to filter the data frame `DF` according to values in my vector `BB` which match the groupID column. However, if `BB` contains repetitions, this is not reflected in the result.

Since my vector `BB` includes two values of 1, and two of 5, the output should in fact be:

```
        Date       Data groupID
1 2015-01-01  4.4104202       12
1 2015-01-01  4.4104202       12
3 2015-01-03  2.1557735       16
4 2015-01-04 -0.9880946       24
5 2015-01-05 -0.3396025       35
5 2015-01-05 -0.3396025       35
```

Is there a way to achieve this? And to keep the ordering of the vector `BB` if possible?

Comment: I can see how my question came across that way. I've edited it now. My 'BB' vector needs to match the groupID column, so I cannot use row labels I'm afraid.

Comment: Maybe `DF[match(BB, DF$groupID),]` then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`match()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/match.html) (or [`findInterval()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/findInterval.html)):

```
DF[match(BB,DF$groupID),];
##           Date      Data groupID
## 1   2015-01-01 1.2199835      12
## 1.1 2015-01-01 1.2199835      12
## 3   2015-01-03 1.8141556      16
## 4   2015-01-04 0.2748579      24
## 5   2015-01-05 3.2030200      35
## 5.1 2015-01-05 3.2030200      35
```

(Note that the `Data` column is different because you used `rnorm()` to generate it without calling `set.seed()` first. It is recommended to call `set.seed()` in any code sample where you incorporate randomness so that exact results can be reproduced.)

Comment: Thank you - this does exactly what i'm looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

You can transform `BB` into a `data.frame` and use `merge()` to merge `DF` and `BB` according to their `groupID`, to be specific:

```
dates=seq(as.POSIXct("2015-01-01 00:00:00"), as.POSIXct("2015-01-07 00:00:00"), by="day")
groupID=c(12,14,16,24,35,46,54)
set.seed(1234)
data=rnorm(7,1,2)
DF=data.frame(Date=dates,Data=data,groupID=groupID)
BB=data.frame(groupID=c(12,12,16,24,35,35))
```

Test result:

```
>merge(DF,BB,by="groupID")
  groupID       Date      Data
1      12 2015-01-01 -1.414131
2      12 2015-01-01 -1.414131
3      16 2015-01-03  3.168882
4      24 2015-01-04 -3.691395
5      35 2015-01-05  1.858249
6      35 2015-01-05  1.858249
```